# Why aren'y my CHECK CONSTRAINTS on child tables being utilized by the planner to reduce the size of the plan?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, partitioning, check-constraints

I have a table that is partitioned by month and is used for holding apache log information.  When I run EXPLAIN for a simple query which has a WHERE clause on the same field as the partition CHECKs, I get the same plan whether constraint_exclusion is on or off.  Below is the master table info and two examples of child tables info for Feb and Mar of 2010.  Overall, there is a child table for each month from Feb of 2010 through June of 2011.  On average, each child table has around 100M records.  Also below is the output of EXPLAIN for a simple query, once with constraint_exclusion on and once with it off.  Unfortunately, the CHECK constraints aren't being used to reduce the plan size.  Is this due to the fact that request_dt datatype is TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE but the CHECK constraints are DATES?  Any other thoughts?  I have not yet created indexes on request_dt, but according to the documentation that isn't necessary.  I'll be adding them, but I wouldn't think they should impact the use of the CHECK constraints.

I'm using Postgres 8.3.6.

```
spatial_data=# \d rpt.websvcs_logs
                        Table "rpt.websvcs_logs"
          Column          |            Type             |   Modifiers   
--------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------
 id                       | bigint                      | 
 ins_ts                   | timestamp without time zone | default now()
 server                   | text                        | 
 host                     | text                        | 
 request_dt               | timestamp with time zone    | 
 method                   | text                        | 
 url                      | text                        | 
 api_method               | text                        | 
 api_key                  | text                        | 
 geo_type                 | text                        | 
 geo_name                 | text                        | 
 radius                   | text                        | 
 lat                      | text                        | 
 long                     | text                        | 
 id_param                 | text                        | 
 state                    | text                        | 
 max                      | text                        | 
 sort_by                  | text                        | 
 sort_dir                 | text                        | 
 rpp                      | text                        | 
 page                     | text                        | 
 ver                      | text                        | 
 output                   | text                        | 
 http_ver                 | text                        | 
 status                   | text                        | 
 size                     | text                        | 
 x_forwarded_for          | text                        | 
 referrer                 | text                        | 
 agent                    | text                        | 
 accept_encoding          | text                        | 
 processing_time_sec      | text                        | 
 processing_time_microsec | text                        | 


spatial_data=# \d rpt.websvcs_logs_201102
                    Table "rpt.websvcs_logs_201102"
          Column          |            Type             |   Modifiers   
 --------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------
 id                       | bigint                      | not null
 ins_ts                   | timestamp without time zone | default now()
 server                   | text                        | 
 host                     | text                        | 
 request_dt               | timestamp with time zone    | 
 method                   | text                        | 
 url                      | text                        | 
 api_method               | text                        | 
 api_key                  | text                        | 
 geo_type                 | text                        | 
 geo_name                 | text                        | 
 radius                   | text                        | 
 lat                      | text                        | 
 long                     | text                        | 
 id_param                 | text                        | 
 state                    | text                        | 
 max                      | text                        | 
 sort_by                  | text                        | 
 sort_dir                 | text                        | 
 rpp                      | text                        | 
 page                     | text                        | 
 ver                      | text                        | 
 output                   | text                        | 
 http_ver                 | text                        | 
 status                   | text                        | 
 size                     | text                        | 
 x_forwarded_for          | text                        | 
 referrer                 | text                        | 
 agent                    | text                        | 
 accept_encoding          | text                        | 
 processing_time_sec      | text                        | 
 processing_time_microsec | text                        | 
Indexes:
    "pk_websvcs_logs_201102_id" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Check constraints:
    "request_dt" CHECK (request_dt >= '2011-02-01'::date AND request_dt < '2011-03-01'::date)
Inherits: rpt.websvcs_logs


spatial_data=# \d rpt.websvcs_logs_201103
                    Table "rpt.websvcs_logs_201103"
          Column          |            Type             |   Modifiers   
--------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------
 id                       | bigint                      | not null
 ins_ts                   | timestamp without time zone | default now()
 server                   | text                        | 
 host                     | text                        | 
 request_dt               | timestamp with time zone    | 
 method                   | text                        | 
 url                      | text                        | 
 api_method               | text                        | 
 api_key                  | text                        | 
 geo_type                 | text                        | 
 geo_name                 | text                        | 
 radius                   | text                        | 
 lat                      | text                        | 
 long                     | text                        | 
 id_param                 | text                        | 
 state                    | text                        | 
 max                      | text                        | 
 sort_by                  | text                        | 
 sort_dir                 | text                        | 
 rpp                      | text                        | 
 page                     | text                        | 
 ver                      | text                        | 
 output                   | text                        | 
 http_ver                 | text                        | 
 status                   | text                        | 
 size                     | text                        | 
 x_forwarded_for          | text                        | 
 referrer                 | text                        | 
 agent                    | text                        | 
 accept_encoding          | text                        | 
 processing_time_sec      | text                        | 
 processing_time_microsec | text                        | 
Indexes:
    "pk_websvcs_logs_201103_id" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Check constraints:
    "request_dt" CHECK (request_dt >= '2011-03-01'::date AND request_dt < '2011-04-01'::date)
Inherits: rpt.websvcs_logs


spatial_data=# SET constraint_exclusion = on;
SET
spatial_data=# EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rpt.websvcs_logs WHERE request_dt = DATE '2011-03-05';
                                              QUERY
PLAN                                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=85738875.50..85738875.52 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..85738236.41 rows=255636 width=0)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=1 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201002 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..564425.36 rows=1387 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201003 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..1546537.50 rows=4287 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201004 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..2528697.60 rows=9248 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201005 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..3164403.20 rows=12885 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201006 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..4476196.10 rows=12035 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201007 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..4470579.60 rows=9543 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201008 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..4881312.70 rows=11071 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201009 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..4433474.70 rows=11005 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201010 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..5419184.20 rows=13605 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201011 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..5562311.50 rows=15424 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201012 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..5543114.80 rows=14961 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201101 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..7320972.20 rows=23008 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201102 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..7413710.90 rows=23898 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201103 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..8754694.20 rows=27241 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201104 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..9292596.80 rows=30848 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201105 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..9148734.80 rows=30727 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201106 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..1217213.25 rows=4456 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)



spatial_data=# SET constraint_exclusion = off;
SET
spatial_data=# EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rpt.websvcs_logs WHERE request_dt = DATE '2011-03-05';
                                              QUERY PLAN                                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=85738875.50..85738875.52 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..85738236.41 rows=255636 width=0)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=1 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201002 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..564425.36 rows=1387 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201003 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..1546537.50 rows=4287 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201004 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..2528697.60 rows=9248 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201005 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..3164403.20 rows=12885 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201006 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..4476196.10 rows=12035 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201007 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..4470579.60 rows=9543 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201008 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..4881312.70 rows=11071 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201009 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..4433474.70 rows=11005 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201010 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..5419184.20 rows=13605 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201011 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..5562311.50 rows=15424 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201012 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..5543114.80 rows=14961 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201101 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..7320972.20 rows=23008 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201102 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..7413710.90 rows=23898 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201103 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..8754694.20 rows=27241 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201104 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..9292596.80 rows=30848 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201105 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..9148734.80 rows=30727 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
         ->  Seq Scan on websvcs_logs_201106 websvcs_logs  (cost=0.00..1217213.25 rows=4456 width=0)
               Filter: (request_dt = '2011-03-05'::date)
```

Comment: Do you mind replacing your EXPLAIN output above with the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE? I think that might be more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the type of **request_dt** column to DATE, or change the **check constraints** to work with timestamp. In the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html), you can see an example with a date type column.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  I changed the CHECK CONSTRAINTS to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE as well as the sample basic query.